# how can i get all the system notifications that are shown now?

Tags: android, notifications

how can i get all the system notifications that are shown now?i want to write a programe that can intercept the notifications that other apps notified.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interfere with another appliactions notifications so it will not be possible to write such application.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/73cc6d5a60386be8) from the Android Beginners Google group answers the question with a solid "No." Quoting a user from the thread:

> No, sorry. Intercepting notifications,
>   in particular, would be quite the 
>   security loophole.  In general, on
>   Android, one application cannot see or
>   mess with another  application's
>   stuff. So, while your desired features
>   would be  interesting for the OS
>   itself, they aren't going to be very
>   practical to  implement in an
>   application written to the SDK.

Comment: @gray comtois,from your answer,it seems we cannot produce our own status bar...ok.thank you very much.